# Difficulty adding new folder in network root directory

Tags: filesystems, network-share

Hey I hope you all are having a good day here. I started a position at a new company and am working to add a new file directory at the root level of our network drive called \\data. When I go to add a new folder, however, I do not have the option to do so. I have logged into our Domain controller with administrative privileges but am still having the issue. I have checked authority settings and confirmed that I have administrator rights. As a note, I can add folders below the root level. I have attached screenshots of what I am seeing when I look to add a folder. I was hoping to see if anyone had any input on this. Thank you very much for your help and let me know if any additional info would be helpful. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydRzq.png)

Answer (score 1):

the data you are showing in the image is a PC named data. The folders to the right (ex. VAN and WSUSContent) are network shares on the data pc.  To add a folder share in that respect, you need to logon to the data PC and create a new share named data.

Comment: Thanks KB126! I was able to log into the Data PC and get the new folders added like you said. Thanks again for your help!